# Print the matched array string values in php

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

I am trying to print the array values of coupon_name. When I try this code,

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.couponrani.com/');

$coupon_name = array();

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
        $coupon_name[] = $element->alt . '<br>';
$find = in_array('coupon',$coupon_name);
  if ($find == false ) { 
        print_r($coupon_name);
  }

 }
    ?>
```

But, What I got the result is: for example my array has (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) this values,

```
Array ( [0] => 1
) Array ( [0] => 1
[1] => 2
) Array ( [0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
) Array ( [0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 4
) Array ( [0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 4
[4] => 5
) Array ( [0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 4
[4] => 5
[5] => 6
)
```

like this going on up to 9 for example.

But, What it need is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Guide me what is my mistake. Because, I am fresh to php.

Comment: Why did you make `$coupon_name` an array if you don't want to use it as an array when you print?

Comment: No, I wanted to print the array values of '$coupon_name' , which has the string 'coupon' and when it matches the string in the array, then the matched string should be printed.

Comment: But, you are printing the array after each time you add an item. Either don't use an array or wait until you've added all the items to print the array.

Comment: yes, But when I do like this , for example..

`foreach($html->find('button') as $element) {
// push the cell's text to the array
$rowData = $element->{'data-coupon'} . '<br>';
if($rowData != ''){
//$query = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO couponcode(codes) VALUES ('$rowData')",MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT );
print_r($rowData);
}

}`

Comment: It prints to me that...

`ZIV100CRANI
ADMCR25
ADD30PER
FVCRANI
SUPER30
hkcr10
CPNR10
DIG359
FDRIVE
HDFCDF
FURNITURE40
SWIGGYOMGCB100
ADV07
DELIGHT
FC250CSF
SBIDFL
ZIVAME15CRN
CRANITITAN
CRANI400`
it gives the exact coupon code i want. Which prints from array.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
        $coupon_name[] = $element->alt . '<br>';
$find = in_array('coupon',$coupon_name);
  if ($find == false ) { 
        print_r($coupon_name);
  }

 }
```

to:

```
   foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
                $coupon_name[] = $element->alt . '<br>';
                $result = array();      
    $find = in_array('coupon',$coupon_name);
      if ($find == false ) { 
            array_push($result,$coupon_name);
      }
     }
print_r($result);
```

Comment: When I do this it will print only one line with the matched string `coupon` other line will not print. Because there are many strings with word `coupon`. So, I need to printed all.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It prints the entire array. Not the values which only matches with the string `coupon`.

Comment: @BalajiSaravanan you should then append all the result in the array using array_push() method http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp and then print the whole result outside the loop.

Comment: I dont want to do that...just see the post comment. I have written the another example.

Comment: Oh my god..!! It prints what I mentioned in the post already.